# How to add custom js file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to add two custom jquery bootstrap files

> jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js
>
> gsdk-bootstrap-wizard.js

Added both files in

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/js/customwizard/

Created a `requirejs-config.js` in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/`

Added following code in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            jquerybootstrapwizard: "js/customwizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard",
            gsdkbootstrapwizard : "js/customwizard/gsdk-bootstrap-wizard"
        }
    },
    shim:{
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jquerybootstrapwizard': {
            deps: ['jquery','jquery/ui']
        },
        'gsdkbootstrapwizard' : {
            deps: ['jquery','jquerybootstrapwizard']
        }
    }
};
```

In my phtml file, I added following script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "gsdkbootstrapwizard" : {}
            }
        }
</script>
```

When I look into my network section, both the files were loaded.

[image]

But I get this error in console

[image]

**bootstrapWizard** is not a function, but this function is present in `jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js` file.

Content of **jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js** file

```
(function  () {
    require(["jquery","jquery/ui"], function ($) {
        var bootstrapWizardCreate = function (element, options) {
            var element = $(element);
            var obj = this;

            // selector skips any 'li' elements that do not contain a child with a tab data-toggle
            var baseItemSelector = 'li:has([data-toggle="tab"])';

            // Merge options with defaults
            var $settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.bootstrapWizard.defaults, options);
            var $activeTab = null;
            var $navigation = null;

            this.rebindClick = function (selector, fn) {
                selector.unbind('click', fn).bind('click', fn);
            }

            this.fixNavigationButtons = function () {
                // Get the current active tab
                if (!$activeTab.length) {
                    // Select first one
                    $navigation.find('a:first').tab('show');
                    $activeTab = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':first');
                }

                // See if we're currently in the first/last then disable the previous and last buttons
                $($settings.previousSelector, element).toggleClass('disabled', (obj.firstIndex() >= obj.currentIndex()));
                $($settings.nextSelector, element).toggleClass('disabled', (obj.currentIndex() >= obj.navigationLength()));

                // We are unbinding and rebinding to ensure single firing and no double-click errors
                obj.rebindClick($($settings.nextSelector, element), obj.next);
                obj.rebindClick($($settings.previousSelector, element), obj.previous);
                obj.rebindClick($($settings.lastSelector, element), obj.last);
                obj.rebindClick($($settings.firstSelector, element), obj.first);

                if ($settings.onTabShow && typeof $settings.onTabShow === 'function' && $settings.onTabShow($activeTab, $navigation, obj.currentIndex()) === false) {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            this.next = function (e) {

                // If we clicked the last then dont activate this
                if (element.hasClass('last')) {
                    return false;
                }

                if ($settings.onNext && typeof $settings.onNext === 'function' && $settings.onNext($activeTab, $navigation, obj.nextIndex()) === false) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Did we click the last button
                $index = obj.nextIndex();
                if ($index > obj.navigationLength()) {
                } else {
                    $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + $index + ') a').tab('show');
                }
            };

            this.previous = function (e) {

                // If we clicked the first then dont activate this
                if (element.hasClass('first')) {
                    return false;
                }

                if ($settings.onPrevious && typeof $settings.onPrevious === 'function' && $settings.onPrevious($activeTab, $navigation, obj.previousIndex()) === false) {
                    return false;
                }

                $index = obj.previousIndex();
                if ($index < 0) {
                } else {
                    $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + $index + ') a').tab('show');
                }
            };

            this.first = function (e) {
                if ($settings.onFirst && typeof $settings.onFirst === 'function' && $settings.onFirst($activeTab, $navigation, obj.firstIndex()) === false) {
                    return false;
                }

                // If the element is disabled then we won't do anything
                if (element.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(0) a').tab('show');

            };
            this.last = function (e) {
                if ($settings.onLast && typeof $settings.onLast === 'function' && $settings.onLast($activeTab, $navigation, obj.lastIndex()) === false) {
                    return false;
                }

                // If the element is disabled then we won't do anything
                if (element.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + obj.navigationLength() + ') a').tab('show');
            };
            this.currentIndex = function () {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index($activeTab);
            };
            this.firstIndex = function () {
                return 0;
            };
            this.lastIndex = function () {
                return obj.navigationLength();
            };
            this.getIndex = function (e) {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index(e);
            };
            this.nextIndex = function () {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index($activeTab) + 1;
            };
            this.previousIndex = function () {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index($activeTab) - 1;
            };
            this.navigationLength = function () {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).length - 1;
            };
            this.activeTab = function () {
                return $activeTab;
            };
            this.nextTab = function () {
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + (obj.currentIndex() + 1) + ')').length ? $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + (obj.currentIndex() + 1) + ')') : null;
            };
            this.previousTab = function () {
                if (obj.currentIndex() <= 0) {
                    return null;
                }
                return $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + parseInt(obj.currentIndex() - 1) + ')');
            };
            this.show = function (index) {
                if (isNaN(index)) {
                    return element.find(baseItemSelector + ' a[href=#' + index + ']').tab('show');
                }
                else {
                    return element.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + index + ') a').tab('show');
                }
            };
            this.disable = function (index) {
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + index + ')').addClass('disabled');
            };
            this.enable = function (index) {
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + index + ')').removeClass('disabled');
            };
            this.hide = function (index) {
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + index + ')').hide();
            };
            this.display = function (index) {
                $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + index + ')').show();
            };
            this.remove = function (args) {
                var $index = args[0];
                var $removeTabPane = typeof args[1] != 'undefined' ? args[1] : false;
                var $item = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + ':eq(' + $index + ')');

                // Remove the tab pane first if needed
                if ($removeTabPane) {
                    var $href = $item.find('a').attr('href');
                    $($href).remove();
                }

                // Remove menu item
                $item.remove();
            };

            var innerTabClick = function (e) {
                // Get the index of the clicked tab
                var clickedIndex = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index($(e.currentTarget).parent(baseItemSelector));
                if ($settings.onTabClick && typeof $settings.onTabClick === 'function' && $settings.onTabClick($activeTab, $navigation, obj.currentIndex(), clickedIndex) === false) {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            var innerTabShown = function (e) {  // use shown instead of show to help prevent double firing
                $element = $(e.target).parent();
                var nextTab = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector).index($element);

                // If it's disabled then do not change
                if ($element.hasClass('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }

                if ($settings.onTabChange && typeof $settings.onTabChange === 'function' && $settings.onTabChange($activeTab, $navigation, obj.currentIndex(), nextTab) === false) {
                    return false;
                }

                $activeTab = $element; // activated tab
                obj.fixNavigationButtons();
            };

            this.resetWizard = function () {

                // remove the existing handlers
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).off('click', innerTabClick);
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).off('shown shown.bs.tab', innerTabShown);

                // reset elements based on current state of the DOM
                $navigation = element.find('ul:first', element);
                $activeTab = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + '.active', element);

                // re-add handlers
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).on('click', innerTabClick);
                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).on('shown shown.bs.tab', innerTabShown);

                obj.fixNavigationButtons();
            };

            $navigation = element.find('ul:first', element);
            $activeTab = $navigation.find(baseItemSelector + '.active', element);

            if (!$navigation.hasClass($settings.tabClass)) {
                $navigation.addClass($settings.tabClass);
            }

            // Load onInit
            if ($settings.onInit && typeof $settings.onInit === 'function') {
                $settings.onInit($activeTab, $navigation, 0);
            }

            // Load onShow
            if ($settings.onShow && typeof $settings.onShow === 'function') {
                $settings.onShow($activeTab, $navigation, obj.nextIndex());
            }

            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).on('click', innerTabClick);

            // attach to both shown and shown.bs.tab to support Bootstrap versions 2.3.2 and 3.0.0
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]', $navigation).on('shown shown.bs.tab', innerTabShown);
        };
        $.fn.bootstrapWizard = function (options) {
            //expose methods
            if (typeof options == 'string') {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
                if (args.length === 1) {
                    args.toString();
                }
                return this.data('bootstrapWizard')[options](args);
            }
            return this.each(function (index) {
                var element = $(this);
                // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
                if (element.data('bootstrapWizard')) return;
                // pass options to plugin constructor
                var wizard = new bootstrapWizardCreate(element, options);
                // Store plugin object in this element's data
                element.data('bootstrapWizard', wizard);
                // and then trigger initial change
                wizard.fixNavigationButtons();
            });
        };

// expose options
        $.fn.bootstrapWizard.defaults = {
            tabClass: 'nav nav-pills',
            nextSelector: '.wizard li.next',
            previousSelector: '.wizard li.previous',
            firstSelector: '.wizard li.first',
            lastSelector: '.wizard li.last',
            onShow: null,
            onInit: null,
            onNext: null,
            onPrevious: null,
            onLast: null,
            onFirst: null,
            onTabChange: null,
            onTabClick: null,
            onTabShow: null
        };
    });
})();
```

Content of **gsdk-bootstrap-wizard.js** file

```
(function  () {
    require(["jquery", "jquerybootstrapwizard"], function ($) {

    searchVisible = 0;
    transparent = true;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        /*  Activate the tooltips      */
        $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        // // Code for the Validator
        // var $validator = $('.wizard-card form').validate({
        //     rules: {
        //         firstname: {
        //             required: true,
        //             minlength: 3
        //         },
        //         lastname: {
        //             required: true,
        //             minlength: 3
        //         },
        //         email: {
        //             required: true,
        //             minlength: 3,
        //         }
        //     }
        // });

        // Wizard Initialization
        $('.wizard-card').bootstrapWizard({
            'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
            'nextSelector': '.btn-next',
            'previousSelector': '.btn-previous',

            onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                var $valid = $('.wizard-card form').valid();
                if (!$valid) {
                    $validator.focusInvalid();
                    return false;
                }
            },

            onInit: function (tab, navigation, index) {

                //check number of tabs and fill the entire row
                var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                $width = 100 / $total;
                var $wizard = navigation.closest('.wizard-card');

                $display_width = $(document).width();

                if ($display_width < 600 && $total > 3) {
                    $width = 50;
                }

                navigation.find('li').css('width', $width + '%');
                $first_li = navigation.find('li:first-child a').html();
                $moving_div = $('<div class="moving-tab">' + $first_li + '</div>');
                $('.wizard-card .wizard-navigation').append($moving_div);
                refreshAnimation($wizard, index);
                $('.moving-tab').css('transition', 'transform 0s');
            },

            onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {

                var $valid = $('.wizard-card form').valid();

                if (!$valid) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            },

            onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                var $current = index + 1;

                var $wizard = navigation.closest('.wizard-card');

                // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
                if ($current >= $total) {
                    $($wizard).find('.btn-next').hide();
                    $($wizard).find('.btn-finish').show();
                } else {
                    $($wizard).find('.btn-next').show();
                    $($wizard).find('.btn-finish').hide();
                }

                button_text = navigation.find('li:nth-child(' + $current + ') a').html();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.moving-tab').text(button_text);
                }, 150);

                var checkbox = $('.footer-checkbox');

                if (!index == 0) {
                    $(checkbox).css({
                        'opacity': '0',
                        'visibility': 'hidden',
                        'position': 'absolute'
                    });
                } else {
                    $(checkbox).css({
                        'opacity': '1',
                        'visibility': 'visible'
                    });
                }

                refreshAnimation($wizard, index);
            }
        });


        // Prepare the preview for profile picture
        $("#wizard-picture").change(function () {
            readURL(this);
        });

        $('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').click(function () {
            wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
            wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(wizard).find('[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).find('[type="radio"]').attr('checked', 'true');
        });

        $('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'true');
            }
        });

        $('.set-full-height').css('height', 'auto');

    });


    //Function to show image before upload

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#wizardPicturePreview').attr('src', e.target.result).fadeIn('slow');
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('.wizard-card').each(function () {
            $wizard = $(this);
            index = $wizard.bootstrapWizard('currentIndex');
            refreshAnimation($wizard, index);

            $('.moving-tab').css({
                'transition': 'transform 0s'
            });
        });
    });

    function refreshAnimation($wizard, index) {
        total_steps = $wizard.find('li').length;
        move_distance = $wizard.width() / total_steps;
        step_width = move_distance;
        move_distance *= index;

        $wizard.find('.moving-tab').css('width', step_width);
        $('.moving-tab').css({
            'transform': 'translate3d(' + move_distance + 'px, 0, 0)',
            'transition': 'all 0.3s ease-out'

        });
    }

    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            }, wait);
            if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };
    });
})();
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think gsdk-bootstrap-wizard.js loaded before jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js so jQuery can't call bootstrapWizard func.

Comment: @Bill can you tell me how to make jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js load before gsdk-bootstrap-wizard.js

Comment: You should remove `$(document).ready(function ()` on gsdk-bootstrap-wizard.js

Answer (score 1):

@Nausif - Please try with following code in requirejs-config.js. Basically I have added dependency tag to load jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js and bootstrap.min.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        jquerybootstrapwizard: "js/customwizard/jquery.bootstrap.wizard",
        gsdkbootstrapwizard : "js/customwizard/gsdk-bootstrap-wizard",
        bootstrapmin : "js/customwizard/bootstrap.min"
    }
},
shim:{
    'jquery': {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'jquerybootstrapwizard': {
        deps: ['jquery','jquery/ui']
    },
    'gsdkbootstrapwizard' : {
        deps: ['jquery','jquerybootstrapwizard']
    }
},
"deps": [
    "bootstrapmin",
    "jquerybootstrapwizard"
], };
```

Comment: I tried above code, works on first reload after clearing my js files from static content, but on second reload its giving the same error